# auth.default.signInWithEmailAndPassword is not a function when using Firebase Auth in React Native app

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I'm currently attempting to use 'signInWithEmailAndPassword' in my React Native application. This is being done within a Context file, and called directly from my sign-in screen. I'm testing this using iOS at the moment.

However, every time I attempt to open the screen, I get the following error:

[image]

The error appears to be happening within my SignInScreen, but I'm assuming that is because I am calling the Context where the error is occurring.

For reference, I have:

- Downloaded and saved my GoogleService-Info.plist file
- Added the config code to my AppDelegate.m file
- Installed @react-native-firebase/app and @react-native-firebase/auth packages and pod installed them too

So I believe my Firebase should be working as expected... So I think this must be an import error, but I've followed the Firebase React Native docs as closely as I can I think.

Here's my code.

SignInScreen:

```
const SignInScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const {signIn} = useContext(AuthContext);

  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  return (
    <View style={styles.parent}>
      <View style={styles.mainView}>
        <SubLemioLogo />
        <Heading title="Sign in to your account" />
        <SubHeading content="This email and password is what you used when you signed up" />
        <Input
          placeholder="Enter email"
          inputValue={email}
          inputText={text => setEmail(text)}
          capitalize="none"
          correct={false}
        />
        <Input
          placeholder="Enter password"
          inputValue={password}
          inputText={text => setPassword(text)}
          capitalize="none"
          correct={false}
          secure={true}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.subView}>
        <CtaButton
          text="Continue"
          onPressFunction={signIn(email, password, navigation)}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

My Context file:

```
import * as firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

export const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);

  const signIn = ({email, password, navigation}) => {
    return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Successfully signed in.');
        navigation.navigate('Dashboard');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{user, signIn}}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Any feedback would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase package use-case has been changed from v5 onwards.

Have a try by using:

```
auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```